# objective-c Odata iPad

Tags: objective-c

I am using Odata client for Objective-C in order to access data in my iPad application. As of now, I have developed a WCF Data Service in .NET and deployed it to the IIS 7.0 in my vista machine and I consumed the service in my iPad/iPhone application and I am able to invoke it, I am getting data in my UITableView of iPad/iPhone application.

When I requested to get list of employees then I got Http Status 200 code at mac console and IIS log (both side) which is okay but when I try to add/update/delete a record using [proxy addToEmployees:employee] [proxy saveChanges]; I got Http Error 500 at both side. When It executes [proxy saveChanges]; statement then it throws the error. I don't know where I am going wrong.

Can anyone help me to figure out the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your WCF Data Service has bug and "crashes". See the IIS/service log files.

Comment: I checked the log, there I am getting the Http Error 500.

Comment: @krishna Patwa: The 500 is the result you see, but it is cause because your WCF Data Service has a bug, and is triggering an exception or other abnormal termination. There should be some hint regarding that or you need to do debug it somehow. I have know idea about WCF Data Service (I don't even know what it is), but that much I know about web programming.

Comment: Thanks buddy. It's resolved now. I had SP's mapping problem in my WCF data services.